# Linq filter returned data repeated

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to filter a list of object using Linq method Where, however, after filter execution the list returned the first element that fulfilled the condition repeated across the whole list (i.e., repeated the number of times for other elements fulfilling the condition too). For example, I am returning employees only with country id = 3 and I should have three employees Green, Blue, and Red, however, I got only Blue repeated 3 times Blue, Blue, Blue.

I am using MySql as my backing store and I am using Entity Framework with MySqlConnection object

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    public IEnumerable<T> SelectAll()
    {
        return db.Set<T>().ToList();
    } 
}


public class AnalyticsRepository : Repository<Analytics>
{
    public new List<Analytics> SelectAll()
    {
        return base.SelectAll().ToList<Analytics>();
    }
}

public IEnumerable<Analytics> SelectByCountryAndProduct(string countrycriteria, string productcriteria)
{
    List<Analytics> result = null;

    using (AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext(factory.GetConnection()))
    {
        db.Database.CommandTimeout = 6000;
        analyticsRepository = new AnalyticsRepository(db);
        result = analyticsRepository.SelectAll();
    }

    return result
        .Where( a => a.CountryId.ToString() == countrycriteria && a.ProductId.ToString() == productcriteria)
        .ToList();
}
```

Debugging and trying another sample solution on a list with dummy data which is worked fine

Comment: Don't use the Repository (Anti-)pattern with Entity Framework because your `DbContext` *is* a repository already.

Comment: Also, your code is very inefficient because you're preemptively calling `ToList` on a `DbSet` object - which means you're loading the entire table into memory and not using runtime generated SQL. Get rid of your `SelectAll` functions and repository types and just call `db.TableName.Where( a => a.CountryId == etc ).ToList()` instead.

Comment: What about using Repository pattern but instead of using a general Repository that works on DbContext Set member I use a Typed Repository that works on the DbSet associated with the Type (i.e., having a Repository interface and being implemented by, for example, CustomerRepository, in which I work on DbContext.Customers DbSet?!. Your words are right and indeed I did not get full usefulness of generated run-time SQL statements.

Comment: What you're proposing is a bad design because it makes it almost impossible to perform actions on related tables if you wanted to query them directly from the parent `DbContext`. It sounds like you want a class that contains useful queries and operations - that's perfectly fine, but you should have them in a single class (either as a `partial class <YourDbContext>` or as extension methods on your DbContext). There really is nothing from the Repository pattern that's applicable to Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew what causes the problem. The problem lies in the Analytics model configuration. I configured the Analytics with a composite key, CountryId and ProductId, respectively. On the other hand, CountryId and ProductId together do not uniquely identify rows within the database. They are repeated across the returned result set. After applying the filter I got only the first occurrence being repeated number of times for other objects that qualify the filter condition. For example, lets say that I have 532 different rows having the same country id and product id after applying the Linq Where I got the first occurrence within the 532 rows being repeated 532 times within the returned list.